# PHP код внутри переменной - все падает из-за кавычек

Tags: php

У меня есть текстовая переменная, в которую сохраняю то, что вводит пользователь через визуальный редактор. Этот текст мне нужно парсить, чтобы вытащить пути картинок.

Проблема в том, когда я сохраняю этот текст в переменную, все падает, когда в этом тексте есть куски PHP-кода со скобочками например:

```
$content = 'q-&gt;getList(["filter"=&gt;['ENTITY_ID']=&gt;$arFields['COMPANY_ID'],"ENTITY_';
```

и все из-за этих одинарных кавычек '.

Есть какие-то варианты работы с таким, как сделать сохранение нормальным, чтоб не падало?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152325/discussion-on-question-by-katy-php--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Вопрос следует закрыть, поскольку он описывает невозможный сценарий.

Answer (score 1):

в *PHP*  есть [одинарные кавычки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) и [двойные кавычки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) и даже ещё один удобный способ в виде HEREDOC.

Предлагаю изучить их и то, как можно комбинировать разные типы кавычек и почему это важно.

В текущем случае скорее всего надо всю строку заключить в двойные кавчки. При этом не забыть у ключа `filter` поменять двойные на одинарные... и `"ENTITY_` тоже.

Ну либо одинарные кавычки заменить на двойные

Comment: да, если подменить кавычки, строка отработает норм. Проблема в том что юзер может вводить как захочет код, с одинарными, с двойными и тд. Видимо значит нужно будет согласовывать, чтоб куски кода бзеры вводили всегда только 1 тип кавычек, чтоб ниче не падало. Если я верно поняла вас

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! 

Comment: @Katy Объясните наконец, КАКАЯ СВЯЗЬ между тем что ВВОДИТ пользователь и тем, что НАПИСАНО ВАМИ в коде?!

Comment: @Ипатьев
Он сохраняется в бд на сервере, и я ее беру с бд для обработки. То есть когда я пытаюсь сохранить такого вида текст в переменную, то код сразу падает с ошибкой, которая характерна тому что код внутри этой переменной начал выполняться. То есть типа syntax error $arFields['COMPANY_ID'] и т.п

Comment: @Katy С КАКОЙ ОШИБКОЙ? Присвоение переменной текста, полученного из БД, не имеет никакого отношения к тому, что вы пишете в коде. Вообще никакого. Код из БД НИКОГДА НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ. Если только вы не делаете что-то совсем дурацкое. Добавьте в свой вопрос код, который вызывает ошибку, и ПОЛНЫЙ ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ. А эту бессмысленную строчку, которая не имеет отношения к вашей проблеме, уберите

Comment: @Ипатьев эта задачу делаю на Битриксе, я думаю вы не совсем поймете если начну объяснять как именно в битриксе его получаю, если вы с ним не знакомы. Но благодарю за ваши комментарии